# R ifelse to generate a new column but the condition column has changed ifself after the process

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to generate a new column using ifelse,the code as follows

```
full_results$group<-ifelse(full_results$P.Value>0.05,"no_change",
                           ifelse(full_results$logFC>2,"up",
                                  ifelse(full_results$logFC<-2,"down","no_change")))
```

And this is the data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIPxN.png)

But, when the process has done, all values of the logFC column has changed into "2"
[here is the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGOWb.png)

How can I keep the values not change?

Answer (score 0):

In the third `ifelse`, there is assignment (`<-`) instead of `<`

```
ifelse(full_results$P.Value>0.05,"no_change",
                           ifelse(full_results$logFC>2,"up",
                                  ifelse(full_results$logFC<2,"down","no_change")))
```